# How to iterate and work on Map key/values using improved Java 8 iterations

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I have read answers stating I can effectively do this:

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    System.out.println("Key : " + key + " Value : " + value);
});
```

But none of the answers provide example on computing something within the `forEach` loop. For instance, if I have a `Map<String, Integer>`, I would like to find how many values have a value of let's say `5`. How do I do this inside the `forEach` loop?

Comment: `map.values().stream().filter(v -> v == 5).count()`. You don't do it in a `forEach` loop, because it's something you're doing with *all* values, not *each* value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for what reason you want to compute this in the `forEach` loop, as there are nicer one-liners as others have already pointed out, but you can do it like this:

```
final int[] count = {0};
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    if (value == 5)
        count[0]++;
});
System.out.println(count[0]);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I admit the example I gave was a poor one. What I actually wanted to compute was equality between two maps with the datatype of the value being List<String>, and so for each mapping I was calling another function to check for equality of the List. I wanted to do all this in a concise way.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `forEach` for this. Instead, I'd stream the map's `values()`:

```
long fives = map.values().stream().filter(v -> v == 5L).count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this shall be using the `Collections` built-in [`frequency`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-) method as

```
Collections.frequency(map.values(), 5);
```